# Breadcrumb library for Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, breadcrumbs

I am looking for a breadcrumb library for codeigniter, I found one called DTE but I'm not sure if I want to use it because it seems all support is gone for the library itself. can anyone recommend one?

Comment: This is the Library I am going to try out. 
http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/99982/

Comment: check this git hub source, http://github.com/benedmunds/CodeIgniter-Breadcrumbs-Library

Comment: Thank you, this guy is making my life much easier.. I am using ion auth as well.